# Acceder a elemento de objeto retornado a la vista mediante blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando con blade laravel, necesito acceder a los elementos internos de un arreglo que retorno a mi vista desde el controlador, esta es el resultado cuando realizo un dd
[![Arreglo][1]][1]

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola user3532954, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  saludos!

Comment: he intentado acceder con foreach al la propiedad del objeto
@foreach($data as $dat)
    <td>{{$dat}}</td>
@endforeach
este es un ejemplo

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega la información (como texto) del método del controlador y de la vista.

Comment: Eso parece más un objeto json que un Array php. Por favor añade el método del controlador para que veamos que esta pasando. Si fuese un Array no deberías tener problema en recorrerlo con foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que me imagino que ha hecho es preguntar haciendo un debug de dd() a su variable desde el controlador. Y lo que quieres, es acceder a los datos de ese arreglo desde las vistas si mal no he interpretado. Es cierto que la pregunta deja que desear, sin embargo, te expongo una respuesta rápida.

Existen varias formas / métodos de pasar los datos a las vistas. Te explico 2 y el resto en la documentación, te recomendaría hecharle un ojo.

Cuando retornas en tu controlador a la vista, puedes hacer

`Return view('carpeta.plantilla', compact('array,objeto,array2,objeto2'));`

De esta primera forma, puedes pasar tantos arreglos como desees, aunque generalmente, si es un array o arreglo sencillo te recomiendo utilizar la segunda opción.

Con la primera opción, por ejemplo, podrías hacer un "query de entradas de la base de datos en tu controlador", almacenar directamente el query u objeto en una variable y pasarla por compact.

Luego en tus vistas, tan solo hacer

`@foreach($objeto as $obj)
{{ $obj->id }}
@endforeach`

Accediendo a cada objeto en cada vuelta, y a su id dentro de la misma.

Como segunda opción puedes utilizar "With"

`return view('carpeta.plantilla')->with($array);`

Y la razón por la que te recomendaba utilizar el with para arrays sencillos u/o asociativos, es porque desde las vistas, podrás acceder a los valores del array de forma directa.

Por ejemplo si tienes

`$array = ['parametro1' => 'grande', 'parametro2' => 'pequeño'];`

`return view('carpeta.plantilla')->with($array);`

Y en tus vistas tan solo debes poner:

{{ $parametro1 }} Y automaticamente accederias al valor del array que pasaste por with.

Digamos que lo que hace with, es "guardar variables accesibles para la vista"

Mi recomendación es 1º pensar bien como deseas o vas a mostrar tus datos en las vistas y que uso le vas a dar a los mismos. El segundo paso, ir a la documentación y ver que otras formas distintas pudieras utilizar y elegir la que mejor se adapte a tu lógica y carga de la misma.

Espero que te ayude.

Saludos!